# How to link analog output and analog input in simulated DAQ device?

Tags: labview, simulate, daq-mx

I simulate NI PCI-6110 device in NI MAX. In LabView I need to send some signal on AO0 of this device and read THIS signal from the device in other scope (doesn't matter read from AO0 or AI0). 
How to configure redirect from AO to AI?

I could link AI and AO with a wire on real/physical device, but I don't know how to do this on simulated device.

LabView 2013 x86.

Answer (score 1):

The simulated input data for DAQmx devices is always going to be a sine wave when called in LabVIEW. If you want to test how your application will respond (in this case output a voltage on the 6110) based on an input, you're going to need to simulate both the input and output with custom code.

I do this by placing a case structure around the DAQmx VIs, with a "Debug?" control OR'd with a "Debug?" global to toggle simulated data. Then in the debug cases you will need to write new code that simulates the acquisition/generation. This allows you to switch between simulated and real data fairly easily for unit testing or integration testing.